# what to do to make oilless, butterless, eggless cookies?

Tags: baking, substitutions, cookies

I am making a cookie dough eggless, butterles and oilless. it is coming out spongy like a cake. what should I do to make no spongy cookies?

Comment: What recipe are you using? How long and at what temperature did you bake it?

Comment: I'm confused; are you using some kind of egg and/or fat substitutes? Because that's basically what a cookie *is*. Without that, you are in fact making a very dry cake or even bread.

Comment: You forgot flourless and sugar free.

Comment: No eggs, no butter, no oil - no good

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htxZZKv4pMw

Comment: @nukhet kuzuoglu please edit you recipe in your question, it will make easier to respond for your query

Answer (score 2):

In general, it's not a good idea to mess too much with baking recipes, since they rely heavily on precise reactions between ingredients. However, there are some things you can try.

For most baking applications, you can *replace the eggs with yogurt* (Greek yogurt will give you extra tanginess and more calcium, etc. - see here for substitution guidelines: http://chobani.com/community/blog/2011/04/chobani-kitchen-conversion-chart)

I don't know that you'd be able to do without either butter or oil, since the fat is what helps to bind the cookies and give them their texture, but you can (in cakes, muffins, and other more bread-like baking) substitute plain applesauce for the oil (1:1 ratio). Like I said, though, that will most likely change the texture of the cookies. If you're looking to just use a *healthier* oil, then you could use canola, olive, or coconut oil, which are generally better for you than butter or vegetable oil (or Crisco/shortening).

Another option, if you're not too worried about the butter or could use a butter substitute, is this really tasty recipe for eggless cookie dough. It tastes fantastic, and you can eat it raw without worrying about raw eggs, or you can bake it up like normal cookie dough. The recipe is from Vanilla Joy's baking blog: http://www.vanillajoy.com/cookie-dough-for-pregnant-women.html

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, cakey is what you can expect without fat. Typically gingerbread-type recipes.

Only alternative that I can see is a second baking of thin cookies at reduced temp to get brittle-crisp. Aiming for biscotti texture but without fat, not exactly.

Super dense chewy would be possible as squares (pan baked cut after)by reducing liquid but you want cookies...

Answer (score 0):

Try these ..
The use something to substitute the eggs.

http://blog.fatfreevegan.com/2010/02/banana-maple-oatmeal-cookies.html